# Reloading of the js scripts via jquery load /ajax

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, spring

Hi I Am working on a project.The design of the project is like this

```
<html>
<head>
some intail scripts that are needed like bootstrap and jquery  and page specific scripts goes here that is required for the first launch
</head>
<body>
<div id=menu>
<!--we put bootstrap menu here-->
</div>
<div id=container>
<!--we load different html pages here using ajax call inside the div when user clicks on the menu we call page html using ajax and append  it here -->
</div>
<div id=footer>
<!--Footer contents  come here-->
</div>

</body>
```

The problem ,that i am facing is , suppose i designed a page that need a bootstrap and jquery

So i placed the file in the page but these files are also present in the homepage where i am going to load the contents using the ajax.So we end-up having two times jquery and bootstrap on the page , this causes few problems 
like my menu stop working

and if i remove the bootstrap from the page that i am going to load few functionality of the page stop working like 
 bootstrap modals doesn't show up and say undefined functions but bootstrap is present in the main page where i am loading this page html using ajax.

one thing i am sure it a project design flaw but this project is on a level where we cant change the structure .

So i need help that how should i stop reloading of the scripts and maintain every thing working.

One more thing the main page is index.html and back-end is in spring framework

Comment: If I understand your question correctly , you should load the JS and CSS files in each of your HTML page wherever needed.

Comment: @pilot  yes but when i include the js and css on each the problem is that may the js are already present into the index.html like jquery so when i call the page using ajax there will be 2 jquery loaded

Answer (score 0):

I can see two posible solutions:

1. If you are putting full HTML pages into `<div id=container>`, put them into an `iframe`.
2. Stript the HTML header from you imported pages and create an appropratie backbone view to show this contents.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that using simple JQuery $load() over that div is not getting the includes of the main page?

I always add HTML code to my DOM using load and I dont need to include the js or css for every injected page.

```
    $('#container').load("url_controller_where_you_will_render_the_html_to_inject");
```

Comment: Scripts are including but if i add jquery on the page and jquery is also present on to the main page so when i will call the page using load method we have tow jquery loaded which makes certain functionality to not work properly. this is the problem

Comment: Ok, but what I´m saying is why do you need to include the jQuery in the loaded page if you already have on the main page?

Comment: because few functionalty works while not loading and few after re loading ...  but  this in the cas of bootstrap.js not in case of jquery

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. In any case you know that whatever your inject into a div by load it can use all the includes of the page where has been include right?. So if for example you have page A that include jQuery.1.10.js and then in some point you load the page B into the div container, all the code of page B can use jQuery.1.10.js

Comment: yes  but look at the bootstrap case :  i have bootstrap in page a and also in b and when i include page b in page a my bootstrap menu in page a stop working but if i don't use bootstrap in b  and include as according you bootstrap is already present menu works but the bootstrap modals in page b stops working. if i include bootstrap in b modals works but menu stop working this is the problem

Comment: I´m using bootstrap as well and I can tell you that my loaded page can continue using the bootstrap class without have to include for every page. Look firebug I´m pretty sure that error is something else

Comment: ok can you tell me that is this a  good idea loading the html in div or loading in  iframe will be best??

Comment: iFrame has serious security issues, normally I never use iFrame

Comment: Thanks paul can i have your skype or gmail id or facebook??